# Automate the Tile Windows in CMM script

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I want to automate tiling windows horizontally or vertically as part of cmm script.
Basically mouse click for `Window > Tile Vertically`.

This will arrange all the open windows nicely within the T32 window.
Unable to find the command to do this in a CMM script.

Any help here is much appreciated.

Cheers,
Anuraag

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tile vertically or horizontally by command/script, but you can store and reproduce the current window layout.

First arrange the windows, e.g. using `Window > Tile Vertically`, and then use the command e.g. `STOre my_window_layout.cmm WIN`. Afterwards you can run the generated script(`DO my_window_layout.cmm`), which will open and position the windows.

If you look into the generated file, you will see that the windows are arranged uwing the `WinPOS` command. Besides absolute positioning, this command also allows dynamic window sizes using percentage values. See the description of `WinPOS` in ide_ref.pdf for more information.